# Add a border-left to a sidebar (Wordpress Twenty Fourteen theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I have tried every div and class combination to try and do a simple thing on this site I am designing:

http://66.147.242.87/~briantur/poetry/

The simple thing is this: I just want to add a border-left, 1px to the left side of the sidebar (to visually separate it from the content area). I can't seem to do this and it's driving me crazy since I know it's simple. I used Chrome Developer Tools magnifying glass and still can't figure it out. Any help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content-sidebar{
    border-left: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Now that that works, is there any way to add a margin to the top of just the line, so it's not touching the green of the background?

Comment: You could just add a `margin-top` to the whole div, which looks fine to me.  You can't add a margin to a border, though.